# Initialize Component on demand

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I would like to initialize component on demand, which contains Bootstrap modal (ng2-bootstrap). This is a component for settings and I don't want it to eat resources if not required (it makes a few requests in `ngOnInit` etc).

I could solve the solution this way

```
<some-settings *ngIf="loadSettings" #someSettings></some-settings>
```

And initialize using `this.loadSettings = true;`

The problem is, if I try to open modal inside SomeSettings immediately it will throw an error, since it doesn't exist yet.

Any better idea how to deal with this? I could open modal from SomeSettings in `ngAfterViewInit`, but I assume there is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the loadSettings property in your SomeSettings component? Why not put it in the parent component?

Comment: loadSettings IS in parent component. The problem is when I change loadSettings to true #someSettings doesn't exist yet